# How to get current position from embedded flash videos?

Tags: flash, swfobject

I'm using SWFObject to embed Flash Videos. Is there a way to get notified as soon as the user hits some specific time marks of the embedded video? I.e. get a notification from the Browsers Flash Plugin?

My goal is to change the page content at specific times of the embedded video.

Thanks,

Sebastian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what player you are using, you could change the the page content based on what point the player's timer is at.

For instance, in the jwplayer, here we get the current time of the video:

```
var player = null;
function playerReady(thePlayer) {
   player = document.getElementById(thePlayer.id);
   player.addModelListener('TIME','playTracker');
}
function playTracker(eventData) {
   alert(eventData);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add cuepoints to the movie when you create the flv (or at runtime using addASCuePoint), when the cue points are reached you could then use ExternalInterface to call a javascript function.